# Is there any better way to import csv file through Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, csv

I need to import a CSV file into Excel which may contain half-a-million records. The sample data looks like as given below.

```
1010000000002,,20190624,Y,987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",123456789012345678909765432101234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10",987654321098765432103216549871234567810,
"CN = OCA1,OU = 10"
```

As you can see, there are columns which contain "," within double quotes and the numbers more than 13 and 16 char in length. If OpenText is used then column value like "CN = OCA1,OU = 10" inserted into 2 separate columns and numbers are also distorted. If OpenFile method is used, then the numbers are appearing with 'E' values. Preserving the data format is essential as this need to exported back into a CSV file. Solved the problem for time-being using FileSystemObject.ReadLine & Split methods. But this will not work for half-a-million record file.

Is there any better way to import large volume of data from a CSV file into Excel without distorting the data format?

Comment: Do you need numbers like `987654321098765432103216549871234567810` to be used as numbers or do you need it as text? Excel cannot deal with large numbers as that.

Comment: Need that as text as there is no mathematical operation done on that.

Comment: Then open the csv file in excel and use the Text To Columns functionality. There you can select a delimiter - should be a `,` in your case - and the data type for each column. For the numbers you should select text, otherwise excel will interpret them as numbers and will trim them since they are too large to handle.